# AndroidTV: Turn display off/on via adb without loosing wifi?

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

I have an Android TV for which I want to turn the display on and off based on a motion sensor. I have connected the tv to a raspberry pi via Wifi and I'm trying now via adb commands to turn off the display of the Android TV.

As far as I've seen, I need to execute the following command:
`./adb shell input keyevent 26`

Unfortunately, this also turns down the device and most importantly Wifi. After this the TV is offline and not reachable anymore via the IP address. So I have to use the remote to turn it on again.

So I need a way to keep the Wifi active. I've already tried the following commands without luck:

```
adb shell svc power stayon true  
adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 3
```

I've also sideloaded a Wakelock app, but that also didn't work. After keyevent 26, the device is always offline.

The TV is a TCL 43P615.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There would not be a standard way of turning off the screen (https://support.google.com/androidtv/thread/58069060/is-it-possible-to-turn-screen-off?hl=en-GB) but perhaps your TV provides one in settings or eco-mode.

Perhaps you best bet is to disable the screensaver and create a completely black fullscreen Activity that you can start and stop from `adb`.